# JSF p:blockUI is not working with LazyDataModel

Tags: jquery, jsf, lazy-loading, blockui

I'm using LazyDataModel to load data in pages and with commandButton when I call the search method I see a response for the POST method as below

```
<partial-response id="j_id1"><redirect url="/test-faces/spring/main?execution=e3s2"></redirect></partial-response>
```

I'm triggering blockUI for the commandButton action and the blockUI dissapears before first set of results to appear.

My question is how to keep blockUI progress bar until first set of results appear in the table.

### Thanks

Comment: *how* are you triggering the blockUI?

Comment: <p:blockUI block=":cont"  trigger="sForm:findItems" widgetVar="blockUIWidget"   >
   <p>Loading
    blocked content.</p>
   <p:graphicImage value="/images/bg.gif" />
  </p:blockUI>

Comment: <p:commandButton id="findItems" value="Find Items"
        action="search" update="@form"  />

Comment: This is how I trigger blockUI

Comment: Remove the `update="@form"`. That'll effectively cause a full-page refresh, killing the blockUI mid-operation